# Merging columns with the same name

Tags: excel

I have tried the built-in Get & Transform merge tool, but it is not producing the result that I want. I have a workbook, for example:

[image]

A copy of this workbook is given to multiple users who go and collect data to fill in a portion of the workbook. Bob may only go to Location "1" to get prices for the items at that location. Jane may only collect for Location "12".

Is it possible to merge all of the partially filled-in workbooks to create a workbook with all of the information filled in where it should be as if a single person did all of the data entry?

Comment: I can think of several ways to do what you ask, possibly with VBA. but your question is currently too broad to give a succint answer. I would recommend you edit and specify in what way the Get & Transform tool fails to do what you expect it to do, that would increase the chance of a good answer.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Bob may enter the following:

[image]

... and Jane:

[image]

Using Get & Transform with the default settings gives:

[image]

What I would like after merging is:

[image]